# Can't get weather API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get JSON data from openweathermap.org, but $.getJSON doesn`t work.
If I call API from browser it display JSON data, but it doesnt work in JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(location,error,{timeout:10000});       
});
function location(pos){
    $("#crd").html("Location: " + pos.coords.latitude + " , " + pos.coords.longitude);

    $.getJSON("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+pos.coords.latitude+"&lon="+pos.coords.longitude+"&APPID=key", function(json){
        $("#weather").html(JSON.stringify(json));
    });

}
function error(err){
    var errorCode = "";
    switch(err.code) {
    case err.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        errorCode = "User denied the request for Geolocation.";
        break;
    case err.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        errorCode = "Location information is unavailable.";
        break;
    case err.TIMEOUT:
        errorCode = "The request to get user location timed out.";
        break;
    case err.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        errorCode = "An unknown error occurred.";
        break;      
    }
    $("#crd").html("Error " + err.code + ": " + errorCode); 
}   
});
```

One more problem. It worked on localhost when I add http://, but it doesn`t work in codepen. Any idea?

I found solution that in codepen you need to use some cross-origin like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You'll have to anchor the address for it to properly refer to another domain. You can do that by adding `//` at the start (and optionally a protocol) – `"//api.openweathermap.org/..."`. Otherwise, the address is treated as relative to the current page and `api.openweathermap.org` can also be a valid directory name.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you use used a full URL including scheme (`http://` or `https://`, or possibly just `//` to use the current scheme)

Comment: Note that looking at the request in your favorite browser's inspector / development tools would probably have highlighted the issue pretty quickly.

Comment: ...and then there's the whole [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue: Unless they whitelist your page's origin (or allow all origins), you can't access that endpoint via ajax. (You could with JSONP if they support it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missed the sheme: `http://` try with this:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+pos.coords.latitude+"&lon="+pos.coords.longitude+"&APPID=key", function(json){
    $("#weather").html(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

Comment: @Viktor no problem, please mark the answer as correct.